# Multiply an array by a 2D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

The goal of this code is to multiply a single dimension array by a 2dimension array by column. product array below is what i am attempting to get and print

The error i am facing is in the method **outputArray**,

example output:

```
arrayOne[] = 2,4
arrayTwo[][] = 2,4,6
               8,10,12
productArray = (2*2 + 4*8) , (2*4 + 4*10) , (2*6 + 4*12)
```

---

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here   
        description();
        int arrayLength = getLength();
        double[] arrayOne = getArrayOne(arrayLength);
        int numCol = getNumColumn();
        int rows = numCol;
        double[][] arrayTwo = getArrayTwo(rows, numCol);
        outputArray(arrayOne, arrayTwo, rows, numCol);
    }


    public static int getLength() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the length of the first array");
        int length = input.nextInt();
        return length;
    }


    public static double[] getArrayOne(int length) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double array[] = new double[length];
        System.out.println("Please enter the contents of the first array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            array[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }
        return array;
    }


    public static int getNumColumn() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numcolumn;
        System.out.println("Enter the number of columns of the 2D array: ");
        int numColumn = input.nextInt();
        return numColumn;
    }


    public static double[][] getArrayTwo(int rows, int columns) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the contents of the second array: ");
        double array[][] = new double[rows][columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
                array[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        return array;    
    }


    public static void outputArray (double[] arrayOne, double[][] arrayTwo, int rows, int column) {
        double sum = 0;
        Double productArray[] = new Double[column];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            sum += arrayOne[i] * arrayTwo[i][0];
            productArray[arrayOne.length] = sum;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < productArray.length; i++){
            System.out.println(" " + productArray[i]);
        }            
    }


    public static void description() {
        System.out.println("This program will multiply 2 one dimension arrays of any length. The length and the contents of the arrays is entered from the keyboard.");
    }
```

Comment: in main() `int rows = (arrayLength * numCol) / numCol;` is redundant as you multiply and divide by the same number

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's not clear to me what you're asking about in your question. Can you please edit it to make it more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `outputArray()` you are nesting the loops the wrong way; you should have the rows loop inside your columns loop. It should be:

```
    for (int k = 0; k < column; k++) {

        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            sum += arrayTwo[j][k] * arrayOne[j];
        }

        productArray[k] = sum;

    }
```

this prints out the array [36.0,48.0,60.0]

Comment: Next time please say that your code is not working and also post how you know its not working (error messages, incorrect output etc.)

Comment: @user2947074 Accept the answer if they figured out exactly what you wanted